# New to swift. How to create or update a view

Tags: objective-c, swift

In objective c, in a table view or collection view, I often use code like this...

```
// first time for a reusable cell, set up a subview and add it
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:32];
if (!label) {
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    label.tag = 32;
    [cell addSubview:label];
    // other one-time config stuff for label
}
// on the first time and all subsequent times
label.text = // something specific to this row
```

Now, trying to do the same in Swift, I can't do it...

```
var label = cell.viewWithTag(32) as! UILabel
if (label == nil) { <---- compiler error - can't compare non-optional to nil
```

It seems the forced cast makes the label non-optional, and compiler says there's no point in comparing non-optional to nil.  But it is still optional, isn't it?

If I don't force the cast, I can get a little farther, but then the type check gets me...

```
    var label = cell.viewWithTag(32)
    if (label == nil) {
        label = UILabel()
        label?.tag = 32
        label?.textAlignment = .center  <--- compiler error - UIView doesn't have textAlignment
```

How do I do this pattern in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var label = cell.viewWithTag(32) as? UILabel
```

The thing is when you use `as!` you are force unwrapping the value returned from `viewWithTag(_:)`, which is a `UIView?`. When you perform a force unwrap and the value is nil or the type you're casting to mismatches, you get a runtime error. Otherwise it works just fine, and since you have an unwrapped value, there's no point in comparing it to nil. As for `as?`, this is actually an attempt to cast. It won't throw any errors for the cases `as!` would.

Thus, the first time you run the the code I posted above, you will get a `UILabel?` with `nil`. The other times it will still be `UILabel?`, but it'll wrap a (non-nil) `UILabel`.

Comment: Very helpful explanation!  Thank you!

Comment: Better yet, conditionally bind `label` so its wrapped value is directly accessible.